# ¿Cómo eliminar márgenes dentro del plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, margin

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
    ggplot(df_cdt, aes(x = fecha, y = valor)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10, limits = c(0, 170)) + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, nrow = 3, scales = "free_y", 
             strip.position = "left", 
             labeller = as_labeller(c(cdt_prom = "Contracción Diaria \ndel Tronco (µm)", 
                                      dpv = "Déficit de Presión \nde Vapor (kPa)", 
                                      etc = "Evapotranspiración del \nCultivo (mm*dia^-1"))) + 
  labs(x = "Días despues de la poda", 
       y = NULL) + 
  theme_light() + 
  theme(strip.placement = "outside", 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 8)) + 
  geom_vline(linetype = "dashed", 
             size = 2, 
             colour = "grey", 
             mapping = aes(xintercept = 120)) + 
  geom_text(data = datos_anotaciones, 
            mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, label = temporada), 
            alpha = .6) + 
  geom_errorbar(data = df_cdt %>% 
                  filter(variable == 'cdt_prom'), 
                aes(ymin = valor-desv_est, ymax = valor+desv_est))
```

Y obtengo el gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pregunta:
¿Cómo elimino el área sin gráfico antes 0 y después del 160 (en el eje x)?, ya que son espacios sin data?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega a tu gráfico una "capa" para configurar la escala:

```
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 160), expand = c(0, 0)) +
```

Entiendo que tu `x` es un valor continuo por eso `scale_x_continuous`, sino debes buscar el `scale_*` apropiado a los datos. Los `limits` definen de dónde a dónde llega la visibilidad del gráfico y `expand` establece que justamente no se agregue espacio en blanco, en los limites.

Comment: Gracias Patricio!